# Script to filter by most recent end of week date

Tags: sql-server, sql-date-functions

My company's reporting week is Monday through Sunday.  On Monday morning's I run several queries using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to report on business activity for the previous week.  I currently use declaration statements to pull the desired date range.  This works quite well as long as I'm running reports on Monday. However, if Monday was a holiday and I'm not running reports until Tuesday, I need to manually modify my date range for each query.  How can I modify my date filter to retrieve records through the previous "Sunday" so it doesn't matter what day I actually run the report.

Here's a sample query;

```
Declare @DATEFROM SMALLDATETIME = (CONVERT(datetime, getdate() + cast('00:00' as datetime)) - 8), @DATETO smalldatetime = (CONVERT(datetime, getdate() + cast('23:59' as datetime))-2);

Create Table #SALES ([PartNumber] CHAR(5), [DateSold] SMALLDATETIME)

Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10190',  '6/3/2018 11:00'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10213',  '6/8/2018  8:00:00 AM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10214',  '6/5/2018  9:30:00 AM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10215',  '6/4/2018  1:00:00 PM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10217',  '6/6/2018  1:00:00 PM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10219',  '6/7/2018  12:00:00 PM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10220',  '6/9/2018  3:30:00 PM'

Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10221',  '6/11/2018  8:30:00 AM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10222',  '6/11/2018  2:30:00 PM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10225',  '6/8/2018  8:00:00 AM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10227',  '6/10/2018  9:00:00 AM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10231',  '6/10/2018  1:00:00 PM'
Insert Into #SALES   Select   '10233',  '6/2/2018  8:00:00 AM';

SELECT S.PartNumber, S.DateSold 
FROM #SALES S 
WHERE DATESOLD BETWEEN @DATEFROM AND @DATETO 
ORDER BY DateSold;

DROP TABLE #SALES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a few items of interest:

- SQL Server's [`SET DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command allows you to choose any weekday as the first day of the week, from 1 (Monday) through 7 (Sunday).
- You can query the current value of this setting using the expression `@@datefirst`.
- [`DATEPART(weekday, getdate())`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will return a number for the current weekday where 1 indicates the day set by `SET DATEFIRST`, 2 indicates the day after, etc.

So suppose I want to answer the question: how many days prior to some arbitrary date `@TestDate` was the most recent Monday? The number of days that have passed since the most recent beginning of a week is `DATEPART(weekday, @TestDate) - 1`, and the number of days that pass between a Monday and the beginning of a week is `@@datefirst - 1`, so the number of days that have passed since the most recent Monday is the sum of those quantities modulo 7:

```
declare @TestDate date = convert(date, getdate());
declare @DaysPastMonday int = (@@datefirst + datepart(weekday, @TestDate) - 2) % 7;
```

With this information you can get your date range very easily:

```
declare @DateTo date = dateadd(day, -@DaysPastMonday, @TestDate);
declare @DateFrom date = dateadd(day, -7, @DateTo);
```

But note that both of the dates I've selected here are Mondays, whereas you want a Monday through a Sunday. The reason I've done it this way is that if you're going to be looking at fields that potentially have a time component as well as a date (e.g., `datetime` or `datetime2`), and you want to use `BETWEEN`, then you need to make sure that your end date has the latest time of day that SQL Server is capable of representing. I find it cleaner to use a date range that's inclusive on the start date and exclusive on the end date. So in place of an expression like this:

```
x BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
```

You'd write your queries to use an expression like this:

```
x >= @DateFrom AND x < @DateTo
```

Comment: Thank you Richard.  I really appreciate the detail you included in your response!

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @DATEFROM datetime = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0), 
@DATETO datetime = DATEADD(ms, -3, (select DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 7)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Matthew, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I am newly self-taught and I'm aware there several gaps in my knowledge, but I believe I follow this logic and I successfully used it in my weekly reports today.  I even modified it for a couple of month-to-date reports. I have one follow-up question, I don't need a timestamp to show on the report, but I do want to ensure that all orders are captured by calendar date, not the current datetime less X number of days.  Does this declaration statement meet that requirement?.

Comment: Hey K-Jo, sorry, haven't been on in a while and just found your followup question. If I understand your question correctly the code should be fine.  I would just cut off the timestamp in your UI or Print of the actual report but would keep them in your WHERE clause how they are.