# Getting last 6 weeks

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query:

```
SELECT distinct sending_organisation AS [Supplier], t1.date, COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions], Month(t1.Date) SO_Month, Year(t1.date) SO_Year
 FROM TX
   CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CONCAT(left(DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported),3),' ',
                             DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported)),
                      DATEPART(mm, Date_Reported)
                     )
            ) t1 (Date, Morder)

Where Status not in ('defect')
 and Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    GROUP BY t1.date, t1.Morder, sending_organisation
ORDER BY sending_organisation, date DESC
```

This gives me a table with all suppliers, transactions in specific month and year. It gives me the last 6 months of data (ie Feb 2018-July 2018). However, how can I tweak this query to get the last 6 weeks instead?

To be honest, the ideal SQL would give me the date of the last 6 weeks as w/c with the date being the date of MONDAY and the week ends on Sunday. So, if I look at data for last 6 weeks from today, the columns would be like

```
4/06/18 | 11/06/18 | 18/06/18 | 25/06/18 | 02/07/18 | 09/07/18
```

Thanks

Comment: weeks overlap with months and years, so you have to be careful what you mean by 'week 1 of june'

Comment: i mean i don't really care about the month. Just really want a column with the week number or preferably the exact date of beginning of week

Comment: OK so what week should days 29 to 31 be in for each month? 5?

Comment: to be honest the ideal sql would give me the date of the last 6 weeks as w/c with the date being the date of MONDAY and the week ends on sunday. SO if i look at data for last 6 weeks from today the columns would be like

4/06/18
11/06/18
18/06/18
25/06/18
02/07/18
09/07/18

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are after, but ...

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEADD(WEEK, -6, GETDATE()))

... gives you the Sunday (adjust a bit for Monday) of the start of the week six weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try, let me know

```
      --generating a table of weeks in the last 6 months via a recursive CTE

WITH week_table AS (SELECT dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(dw,getdate()), cast(getdate() as date)) [Date]
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT dateadd(day, -7,[Date])  from week_table WHERE [Date] >= dateadd(month,-6,cast(getdate() as date))
                    )

SELECT distinct sending_organisation AS [Supplier], t1.date, COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions]
 FROM [Warehouse].[dbo].[Transactions] TX
   CROSS APPLY ( select [date] from week_table)
             t1 

Where Status not in ('defect')  AND  t1.[date] <= TX.TransDate AND TX.TransDate< dateadd(day,7,t1.[date] ) 

    GROUP BY t1.[date],  sending_organisation
ORDER BY sending_organisation, date DESC
```

--my system gives me week starting sunday - there's work arounds for that, it depends on your SQL settings

Comment: This works but gives me values for each week as the same value.

Comment: do you mean all totals are the same?  Or is it that all week names are the same?

Comment: All totals are the same, week names are fine

Comment: you mean the count(status) is always the no same?  I'm puzzled by that, I can only think to investigate by testing it with no GROUP BY and see how many rows there are

Comment: Yes the count status is the same for each supplier.

Comment: I know what's wrong, it doesn't check that transaction date is in the week date range

Comment: ooo promising!!

Comment: I added a further condition in

Comment: it has to be whatever the date you are interested of,  in TX is - it could be TX.[date] perhaps?  I don't have the name of the field, so i assumed a name

Comment: should it be Date_Reported?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to the [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function is the *datepart*, which you can change from `MONTH` to `WEEK` to get the last 6 weeks instead of the last 6 months.

As for the getting the Mondays of the week, per your ideal SQL, you can use this:

```
dateadd(day, -1 * (datepart(weekday, Date_Reported) - 2), Date_Reported)
```

The `weekday` datepart returns an integer 1 through 7, with Sunday being 1, so you just subtract the weekday value of `Date_Reported` (minus 2 to adjust to Monday) to get the Monday of the week of Date_Reported.

Comment: Yes thanks that will give me last 6 weeks, but i want week number as a column just like i have month and year as a column

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that part.

Comment: I edited my answer to include getting the Monday of the week column.

Comment: Thanks, where do i add the second part of your query on my query?

Comment: You can put it in the ```CROSS APPLY``` clause alongside ```t1.Date``` and ```t1.Morder```, or replace ```t1.Date``` with it if that's how you want to group the data.

Comment: SQL Server allows you to configure any weekday as the "first" day of the week, and the `weekday` datepart returns an index relative to that setting; you can't always assume that 1 indicates a Sunday. This answer won't work if `SET DATEFIRST` has an unexpected value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806140/script-to-filter-by-most-recent-end-of-week-date/50806788#50806788) for an example that works irrespective of that setting.

Comment: IMHO, I think that level of generality is unwarranted, unless you're changing the first day of the week often, but you're ultimately right. +1 on your answer.

Comment: That's a fair point, and I agree that the first day of the week is unlikely to change _ever_, much less often, once it's been established. I do think that degree of generality is important if you can't know how someone reading your answer will have that setting configured in the first place, but I also agree that an individual person implementing the solution could simplify it to assume the specific `SET DATEFIRST` value that their organization uses.